# Multiple graphs with different color lines and markers

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I need to plot multiple graphs with different line colors and markers. 
I want number of graphs to be flexible and plot those automatically.

When I give and array of values to matplotlib.pyplot.plot to plot, it plots them with different colors. However, I couldn't find a way to also add markers on those plots.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_axis = [[252.7, 252.7, 252.7, 252.7, 252.7, 252.7],
       [224.2, 224.2, 224.2, 224.2, 224.2, 224.2],
       [198. , 198. , 198. , 198. , 198. , 198. ],
       [179.2, 179.2, 179.2, 179.2, 179.2, 179.2],
       [148.2, 148.2, 148.2, 148.2, 148.2, 148.2],
       [124.7, 124.7, 124.7, 124.7, 124.7, 124.7],
       [ 97.4,  97.4,  97.4,  97.4,  97.4,  97.4],
       [ 81.3,  81.3,  81.3,  81.3,  81.3,  81.3],
       [ 62.4,  62.4,  62.4,  62.4,  62.4,  62.4]]
y_axis = [[ 98.986099 , 100.165872 ,  99.8226189, 100.563172 , 100.074811 ,
        100.603689 ],
       [ 99.9345974,  99.634039 , 100.126533 ,  99.99223  , 100.264707 ,
        100.165244 ],
       [ 99.97628  , 100.174231 ,  99.991863 ,  99.9305726, 100.114646 ,
        100.006637 ],
       [ 99.8629142, 100.068743 ,  99.7361936, 100.34242  ,  99.9061321,
        100.146376 ],
       [ 99.9580146,  99.9585485, 100.064912 ,  99.9304251, 100.135072 ,
        100.044364 ],
       [ 99.9656089, 100.022012 ,  99.910529 , 100.054065 , 100.194655 ,
         99.9474796],
       [ 99.916351 , 100.05248  , 100.045002 ,  99.8500087, 100.146954 ,
        100.097336 ],
       [ 99.8399431,  99.9708453, 100.040011 ,  99.9784648, 100.05224  ,
        100.262108 ],
       [ 99.9390728, 100.003478 , 100.062155 ,  99.9212035, 100.12125  ,
        100.09437  ]]

plt.plot(x_axis,y_axis)
plt.show()
```

[Plot I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EF2Eq.png)
plt.plot assigns different color to each graph, but the markers are not shown.

I would like to see the markers too, and I want to have different marker styles with the same color as the graphs line

I am new to python, please help!

Comment: Currently your question is highly vague and unclear. To have round markers, you use `plt.plot(x_axis,y_axis, '-bo')`. There is **no data** in your question so no one can run your code. You wrote "I want number of graphs to be flexible" but there is only one graph in your code. Yo haven't included how the final figure should look like. Try including a hand drawn sketch. In short, please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Found the solution ( plt.plot(x,y,'-o') ), thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
plt.plot(x, y, '-o')
```

did the job

Edit:
in the argument '-o', '-' stands for solid line, 'o' stands for circle marker.
Since x and y are arrays, and since there is no specification of color for markers and lines, python plots each graph in different color with solid line and circle marker.